# Generating a list of random Integers in Java (in a Scala-like fashion)

Tags: java, scala, java-8

Is there an equivalent in Java 8 or later to the following in Scala?

```
Seq.fill(n)(Random.nextInt)
```

Comment: [`Random.ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe somewhat closer approximation than `Random.ints()` would be something like this:

```
Stream
  .generate(rnd::nextInt)
  .limit(n)
  .collect(toList());
```

It is "closer" in the sense that, if one ignores minor syntactic differences and `Seq` vs. `List` distinction, both the Scala version and this version unify with a function of signature

```
(Int, Unit => T) => Seq[T]
```

for any `T`:

```
(n, f) => Stream.generate(f).limit(n).collect(toList())
(n, f) => Seq.fill(n)(f)
```

Unlike `Random.ints()`, this version works for more complex distributions, and it actually limits the length to some number `n`, just like the Scala version does. Depending on what you want to do with it, you can `collect` it to some other data structure, or just leave it as `Stream`.

---

Full demo with all imports:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class RandomListGeneration {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int n = 42;
        List<Integer> result = Stream
            .generate(rnd::nextInt)
            .limit(n)
            .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace `() -> rnd.nextInt()` with `rnd::nextInt`. But I don't see the advantage over `Random.ints()`. It has overloads that accept length and range arguments.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for the hint with `rnd::nextInt`, you are of course right. The advantage is that integers can be quickly replaced by "random game states" or "random evolved creatures" or another random generator of arbitrarily complex structures.

Comment: I don't see your point. Both would acquire additional tweaking that case: either `Stream.generate(() -> new State(rnd.nextInt())`, or `rnd.ints().map(State::new)`.

Comment: @shmosel I meant that the solution above generalizes easily to `Stream.generate(myFancyRandom::nextRandomCreature).limit(n)`, whereas the `Random.ints()` doesn't, because the `Random.ints()` has a hard-coded dependency on `Random` and `ints`. If the OP wants only a Stream, but neither the `Random` number generator, nor integer values, then the `Stream.generate` solution is still partially reusable. I don't know which part is more important to the OP. You for some reason focus on `Random` and `Int`. I for some reason have the feeling that the `Stream.generate(arbitrarySupplier)` is important.

Comment: @shmosel Maybe more objective argument would be the following: both `(n, f) => Seq.fill(n){f}` and `(n, f) -> Stream.generate(f).limit(n)` unify with a function that has type `(Int, () -> Int) -> Iterable<Int>`, whereas this is not the case for `Random.ints()`, which is rather `() -> Iterable<Int>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Random.ints(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints(long)) to generate `n` random numbers. To avoid boxing, you probably want to put them into an array:

```
int[] seq = rnd.ints(n).toArray();
```

If you want a list and you don't mind boxing, you can do this:

```
List<Integer> list = rnd.ints(n).boxed().collect(toList());
```

The pseudorandom number generator defined by `java.util.Random` is used if `rnd` is an instance of that class. This should be fine for most purposes. If you want to use a different source of randomness, you can override [`Random.next(bits)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) to supply bits from a custom source instead of from the built-in generator. For example, you can do this:

**WARNING: THIS IS A TERRIBLE SOURCE OF PSEUDORANDOM NUMBERS. DON'T USE IT. THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE.**

```
class MyRandom extends Random {
    int state = 0;
    protected int next(int bits) {
        return state ^= 1;
    }
}

Random rnd = new MyRandom();
int[] seq = rnd.ints(n).toArray();
```

This lets you use your own source of random bits using the API of `java.util.Random`, such as the ability to get values of various primitives, in different distributions, and streams of different types, ranges, and lengths.

Comment: The source of randomness should have nothing to do with the distribution of the generated random values. Trying to influence the distribution of some random numbers by overriding `Random.next` is illegal, because the interface of `next` requires that the bits are IID. To generate interesting distributions of anything non-trivial, one should consider using more powerful frameworks that provide an implementation of the Giry monad anyway, modifying `Random` seems to be inappropriate level of abstraction.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Correct, one mustn't attempt to influence the distribution of pseudorandom values by altering the supply of bits provided by overriding `Random.next`. The different distributions I referred to are provided by `Random` itself, such as `Random.nextDouble` vs `Random.nextGaussian`, using the built-in or provided source of independent random bits. Clearly `Random` isn't the ultimate in pseudorandom generates (the JDK also provides `SecureRandom` and `SplittableRandom`) but it's quite useful for many purposes.

Comment: Alright, then I probably misunderstood why you decided to mention "different distributions" in the last sentence of your posting. What I wanted to say was basically: it's not possible to get any interesting distributions by overriding methods of `Random`. It's a good random number generator, but it doesn't provide anything beyond the most basic distributions on the primitive number types (and that's good, because everything else should be the job of frameworks, not core API). Anyway, thanks for adding the clarification.